# Как в Java gwt программно менять локаль?

Tags: gwt, java

Я новичок в этой области. Пока в браузере получается читать текущую локализацию и список возможных:

```
LocaleInfo.getCurrentLocale().getLocaleName()
```

и

```
for (String s : LocaleInfo.getAvailableLocaleNames()) { ... }
```

Хотелось бы программно (например в диалоге на стороне клиента) устанавливать локаль,
т.е. что-то вроде `setLocaleName(s)`;

Обыскался, ничего не нашел, видимо ищу не там. А вообще такое возможно?

**UPD**

Как было предложено [[@krivenko](/users/269/krivenko)](/users/269/krivenko) попробовал через **Window.open(...)**, локаль поменялась, но как и предполагал приложение перезапустилось с начала.

Вопрос о том, как взять ВСЕ содержимое адресной строки браузера остался, перезапускал я жестко вставив URL в текст программы.

Собственно мне нужно управлять поведением методов классов, расширяющих классы gwt.i18n.client.Messages/Сonstants .

Возможно достаточно будет уметь динамически менять < meta name="gwt:property" content="locale=x_Y">.

Но не могу найти, как к ней подобраться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String address = ...;
String locale = LocaleInfo.getAvailableLocaleNames()[0];
Window.open("address?locale=" + locale, "_self", "");
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо !


Но, как известно, на каждый правильный совет нужно еще 10, как его выполнить...

Собственно следующий вопрос, а как извлечь String address ? Насколько я понимаю, это содержимое поля для URL браузера.


И одно сомнение, а при этом приложение не перезапустится с начала ?
Так получается, если руками добавлять ?locale=ru в окошке браузера.

Comment: Window.Location.getHref()

Comment: @cy6erGn0m Спасибо! Получилось, багаж растет. 

И все-таки как можно переключить локаль без перезапуска приложения ?

Comment: Нельзя. В каком случае это вам понадобилось? Обычно требуется установить локаль при первом запросе пользователя, в зависимости от того, что содержит этот запрос. А когда юзер кликает на локаль, чтобы установить её, всегда происходит перезапуск. Может быть вам нужно изменить локаль по умолчанию?

Comment: Очень жалко. 

Просто сейчас я осваиваю инструмент, а мне нравятся максимально управляемые системы. 

Значит для адаптивных решений надо либо делать свою локализацию приложения, либо как-то сохранять состояние клиента и уметь перезапускаться с него. А как вообще клиент может сохранять историю своей работы между запусками ?  У кого-нибудь есть идеи ?

Comment: С помощью cookies.

Comment: Есть ещё хранилище из набора HTML5, но оно непереносимо. А ещё можно на сервере сохранять, если пользователь логинится. Это часто бывает очень полезно.